# Sitecore 8: RTE showing weird behavior in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, sitecore, rich-text-editor, sitecore8

I have a site recently migrated to Sitecore 8, where we are updating the content using page editor only (due to heavy use of renderings and difficult to update the content using content editor).
But when the page editor opens for some pages in IE 11 and when tried to add the RTE component, it just hangs(Freezes). Unable to proceed after that and have to close the browser forcefully.
It works perfectly fine in Firefox/Chrome. Has anyone encountered these issues?
I am not getting any error message in Sitecore Log, and unable to check anything in browser console as browser hangs and can't do anything.
Please let me know if you have any suggestion to fix this issue.

Comment: You can easily figure out what the problem is from IE's development tool. While you working on, press F12 on the page and try to change Emulation.

Comment: But browser freezes and we are not able to proceed with anything. Also it's happening only for RTE.

Comment: Before freezing happens, open toolbox first and reproduce the issue.

Comment: I can not even switch between F12 and the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this behaviour when I insert multiple components of the same type, where there is no content or surrounding `<div>` tags. For instance a field renderer with no enclosing tags.

For me the solution was to add a `<div>` tag around the normal contents of the component/presentation.